# Need ideas for programming a voicemail to database solution for different clients

Tags: php, twilio, voice-recording

I have a potential customer who's web app needs functionality for multiple (possibly thousands) of users to be able to call in to a phone number and leave a voicemail. They'd need to use some kind of "pin" number that was associated with their account. After calling in and verifying their account with their pin number, they would leave a voicemail that would then get saved in a folder with a reference to their account id and file in the database.

Then they'd log into their account and see a list of MP3's that they have recorded by calling in.

I'm not sure how to get this done. I have taken a look at the Twilio api and i'm thinking maybe its a good solution, but the docs are so intensive i'm not really able to get a good footing to provide a quote.

Any suggestions on how to get this done would be awesome. And if you're an experienced Twilio API user, I'd love to hear if anyone's done anything like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

There are a couple of resources I'd recommend that might help get you up and running with Twilio enough to be able to provide a quote.

So keep in mind that Twilio will help facilitate the telephony part of your app (receiving inbound phone calls, sending voice prompts the caller, letting you know when the user presses buttons on their keypad), but the rest of the app logic should be just creating a standard web app.

To get started I'd recommend walking through the [inbound voice quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/twiml).  This should only take you 15 or so minutes and will get you familiar with the basic concepts of how Twilio works (webhooks and TwiML).

Once you've worked through the quickstart, we actually have a more full feature [How To that demonstrated building a simple voicemail system](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/voicemail).  You can read through that, download the code and even use it as the basis for your own system.

Hope that helps.